# Create getter/setter but without a field member

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin you can create a variable that has both a getter and setter:

```
var mRetrievingConnections: Boolean?

var retrievingConnections: Boolean?
    get() = mRetrievingConnections
    set(value) {
      mRetrievingConnections = value
    }
```

But I am wondering if there is not a way to do this without having to require a private member field. Kotlin states that it has built-in backing fields for setters but how can the getter access this backing field. I am looking for something like this (which isn't allowed):

```
var retrievingConnections: Boolean?
    get() = field
    set(value) {
    }
```

I find this strange because the setter can access the backing field, so whenever you set the value, it automatically gets stored. But how do I retrieve that value in the getter?

Comment: Your code is correct, apart from the fact that `set` doesn't actually set the value, and you need to initialize the `var`. E.g. `var retrievingConnections: Boolean? = null`

Comment: You can access `field` in setter as well `set(value){ field = value }` will work.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Var property has get/set by default.

Comment: @Januson Actually, reading the docs, Kotlin does not say that a var variable has a get/set by default. But gpunto is correct. If I'm not using them, then just leave them out. I simply understood it to mean that there is a difference between a field variable and one that has getters/setters.

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes it does: "default getter and setter implied", "has type Int, default getter and setter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating from my comment, this is the correct code:

```
var retrievingConnections: Boolean? = null
    get() = field
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }
```

Note that this code is equivalent to

```
var retrievingConnections: Boolean? = null
```

So it adds no value if you don't do something more inside `get` and/or `set`